# Django filter list of card types only the latest

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I have a Django model of some different card types

How can I get only the latest of each type in the filter?

cards.filter(card_type__in=[1,2])

Answer (score 0):

You might need group by aggregation for that. The code can be something like this

```py
card_types_dict = cards.values('card_type').annotate(latest_ctime=Max('ctime'))
"""
[
{'card_type':1, 'latest_ctime': 123049234.124654},
{'card_type':2, 'latest_ctime': 123514104.134085}.
...
]
"""

result = {}
for card_type, latest_ctime in card_types_dict.items():
    result[card_type] = cards.filter(card_type=card_type, ctime=latest_ctime).first()
"""
{'1': <Card Object>, '2': <Card Object>, ... }
"""
```